# npm global gulp install

Tags: npm, gulp

Please help me. 
I just start to learning gulp and terminal, i can't install grobal gulp in my Mac.
I was trying all the different way to fix, but it cause more problems..

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "-g" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Christina/Desktop/portfolio/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: 1. If possible, install locally (*without* `-g`).  2. Otherwise, you need to run as a privileged user (e.g. "root").  See also [Give an Account Administrator Privileges](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH10882?locale=en_US)

Comment: If you want to install it globally and require admin privileges, you have to do `sudo npm install -g gulp`. But yeah like what @paulsm4 said, you may not actually need gulp globally.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get it locally on your project and run it with:

```
./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js task
```